# NDK installed in Unity Hub but Unity is not able to access it

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-ndk, android-build

I am building for Android NDK as Google Play Console wants us to. But after Installing Android NDK in Unity Hub. I am not able to access it in Unity.
[Here is a picture of Unity Hub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoHN3.png)

[And here's the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z6xH.png)

I tried installing Android NDK outside of Unity from the android developers website but that didn't work at all. I watched all the videos and read all posts but nothing worked. Am I missing something?
Thanks.

Comment: Make sure that he path to NDK has no spaces. E.g., don't put it under your user directory `C:\Users\Tushar Valid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Unity 2019.3.0. I downgraded to 2019.2 and it worked. It doesn't make any sense but it has also worked for lots of people.

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck the checkbox for NDk and you can download recommended NDK manually from https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads and unzip it
and set NDK path to it.
I hope this is work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many alternative solutions (downgrade Unity version, download NDK from net, change the path of NDK file...) and non of them worked for MAC. Then tried on a windows machine to "build" and volaaaa, it worked!